# Auto intendation in Keil Microvision

Tags: coding-style, notepad++, keil

I am doing a project in C language, in **Keil Microvision** IDE. but the problem is for a new line (pressing enter) causes the next line to start with a ***"tab"*** character and this makes confusing while opening the project in other editors such as notepad++ because the "tab" character is interpreted differently in different editors (*The tab character is represented sometimes 8/4 spces depending upon the editor).*

**So how can I do auto intendation in Keil Microvision which will be standardized in all editors? or is there some softwares to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use spaces instead of tabs, if you want it always to look the same or you can set the tab size in Notepad++/Keil to the same value. But it's up to you to choose between tabs or spaces.

In Kiel, under Edit>Configuration in the Editor tab you can set up the tab size and whether you want to replace tabs with spaces.

I always use a source code indenter on my code anyway, e.g. ([Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/)). This allows you to have your source files (re)formated in a consistent way according to a central config file.